# How can I be notified when a migration fails?

Tags: 8, migrations, notifications

I execute migrations everyday with drush in a bash script but sometimes one migration or more fails. Other times the migration ends with 0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed and 0 ignored. I would also like to be notified of this.

How can I be noticed without watching the logs? Is there a hook or a plugin that runs when the migration ends?

It would be perfect if a mail is sended when the migration ends with an error or the migration ends empty (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed and 0 ignored).

Note: I was thinking on a hook that executes when the migration is finished. Then I could check the migration and send an email if there were an error.

Comment: Sounds a bit off-topic to me as it seems you want to get something returned from your Bash script, no?

Comment: No, I was thinking on a hook that executes when the migration is finished. Then I could check the migration and send an email if there were an error.

Comment: Migrate mostly uses events instead of hooks, take a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Event%21MigrateEvents.php/class/MigrateEvents/8.2.x

Comment: Have you looked through the Migrate module? All possible hooks are in there. Did you find some hook that fits?